# Ubuntu freezing during installation (Copying files)

Tags: system-installation

im trying to install ubuntu for the first time and it freezes every time im trying to install it on the part where it says "Almost finished copying files..." and the only thing i can do after it happens is restarting the computer and starting the whole process again.
any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I had that kind of issue few years back, I was able to install it and get Ubuntu to work by installing it without the Live process. Did you try OEM install ?